# Why does Ubuntu send log info into GNU Screen?

Tags: 14.04, console, logging, gnu-screen

I have several Terminal windows open. Inside one of those terminals, I'm running `GNU Screen` with multiple "tabs". Inside one of those tabs (the one that's active), sometimes logging info appears, *e.g.*

```
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc" lost interfaces
```

Why is that happening? If Ubuntu is anxious to show me some logging info, why that particular terminal and `GNU Screen` tab?